# The client '87c92100-.....' with object id '87c92100....' does not have authorization to perform action

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Rukmini, the SP has contributor role on the subscription not sure why it is erroring and it worked after ading it in a Reader role?
Here is a snapshot
[image]

I am trying some operations from az cli(terraform commands) getting the following error:

> The client '87c92100-.....' with object id '87c92100....' does not
> have authorization to perform action
> 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/read' over scope
> '/subscriptions/f151ee3f-4725-......../resourcegroups/tfmainrg' or the
> scope is invalid

I searched everywhere, RG, AAD, storage account....not able to find where this object or client resdes. Can you please tell me how can I find what object is this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error **"Authorization Failed"** usually occurs if the user does not have access/role to read the resource group.

**To resolve the error**, make sure to assign **`Reader`** role to the user in the subscription level like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Subscriptions -> Select your subscription -> Access control (IAM) -> Add role assignment -> Select Reader*

[image]

You can also use **az cli** to assign the **`Reader`** role to the user by using below command:

> The Owner or User administrator role is required to assign any role.
> So, use another tenant level Owner to assign the role.

```bash
az role assignment create --assignee-object-id UserObjectID --scope subscriptions/SubscriptionID --role reader
```

[image]

***The reader role successfully granted to the user like below:***

[image]

After assigning the role, I am able to read the resource group successfully:

```bash
az group show -n ResourceGroupName
```

[image]

Based on your further requirement you can **assign the roles** by referring to the below MsDoc:

[Azure built-in roles - Azure RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#reader)

Comment: Thanks Rukmini, yes I used the command and it worked fine

Comment: But Rukmini, after issuing the command I see the same service principal twice, as a contributor and reader. On commnd line, when I run terraform plan it works fine but when I run terraform apply I get again the same error Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client '87c92100-......c-133d4db8ed0c' with object id '87c92100-.....0c' does not have authorization to perform action

Comment: Did you grant `contributor` role? and can you paste the complete error.

Comment: 2022-12-13T12:45:42.780+0100 [ERROR] vertex "Error deleting Container Group "weatherapi" (Resource Group "tfmainrg"): ontainerinstance.ContainerGC#Delete: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client '87c-.....-aa6c-133d4db8ed0c' with object id '87c92100.........4' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/delete' over scope '/subscriptions/f151..........-8e3b-/resourceGroups/tfmainrg/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/conta